# Insert variable to <a> html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var test = "Hello"
var $link = $('<a href=""></a>'); 
var timeLine = $link.text(test);

console.log(timeLine);



   })
```

I got [object Object] error. I wanna get `<a href="#"> Hello </a>` as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does work, you just need to append it to a HTML element.

http://jsbin.com/sitihaxipo/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you are not appending your link to your html

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var test = "Hello";   
   var link = $('<a>',{
    text: test,
    title: 'some title',
    href: 'somelink.html'
    }).appendTo('body');
 });
```

Comment: What if I would like to put my link in an other div like: $('<div></div>').text('@' + link).appendTo("body"); I got @[Object Object]